# SPWeb.Fields is empty when iterating through SPWebCollection

Tags: sharepoint-2007

I'm writing a command line application that checks the SPFieldCollection returned by the SPWeb.Fields property, but it's not behaving as I'd like.  I have hundreds of SPWebs and it's definitely touching them all, but for all but the initial SPWeb, it's returning an empty Fields property.  What am I doing wrong?

```
string siteUrl = "http://webroot/sitecoll";
using (SPSite siteCol = new SPSite(siteUrl))
{
    using(SPWeb outerWeb = siteCol.OpenWeb())
    {
        foreach (SPWeb innerWeb in siteCol.AllWebs)
        {
             LogMessageToFile(String.Format("Checking {0}", innerWeb.Url));  //executed for each of the hundreds of innerWebs
             if (innerWeb.Fields.ContainsField("Year"))
             {
                  // Never accessed after the first time through because innerWeb.Fields is empty
             }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`SPweb.Fields` live at the site collection level.

Unless you specifically create the fields at the subsite levels you will get 0 returned.